# DB::table throwing an exception

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I was trying to insert record by using

```
DB::table('action_event')->insert(
   array('message' => 'john@example.com', 'status' => 1, 'id' => '11')
     );
```

it results..

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>    Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer::display() must be an instance of
>   Exception, instance of Error given, called in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\esybound1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\Handler.php
>   on line 279 and defined in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\esybound1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer.php:43
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\esybound1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\Handler.php(279):
>   Illuminate\Exception\WhoopsDisplayer->display(Object(Error)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\esybound1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\Handler.php(158):
>   Illuminate\Exception\Handler->displayException(Object(Error)) #2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\esybound1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Exception\Handler.php(169):
>   Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleException(Object(Error)) #3
>   [internal function]:
>   Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleUncaughtException(Object(Error)) #4 {main} thrown

while i have used the same DB::table query in another controller.. that one running successfully but if i am using same query in any file or controller except the first one it results fatal error... why ?? what would be the reason ??

Comment: What is your laravel and php version? Laravel 5.0 and bellow DO NOT support PHP 7.

Comment: php version is 7.0.10 and laravel version is 4.1